# Liquibase - FileNotFoundException at ZipFile.java

Tags: java, liquibase

When running tests in Jenkins we sometimes have Liquibase fail with a `FileNotFoundException`. This doesn't occur when running locally.

What's strange is the error doesn't occur every build.

**Exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException at ServiceLocator.java:129
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException at ZipFile.java:-2
```

**ServiceLocator**

```
try {
    manifests = resourceAccessor.getResourcesAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
    if (manifests != null) {
        for (InputStream is : manifests) {
            Manifest manifest = new Manifest(is);
            String attributes = StringUtils.trimToNull(manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Liquibase-Package"));
            if (attributes != null) {
                for (Object value : attributes.split(",")) {
                    addPackageToScan(value.toString());
                }
            }
            is.close();
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new UnexpectedLiquibaseException(e);
}
```

We are using `Liquibase 3.8.1`.

What could be causing this?

Comment: are you running test case on cloud?

Comment: @RaushanKumar Yes I believe so. How might that affect it?

Comment: @RaushanKumar It's an Amazon EKS Cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is happening due to the log4j security patch update on AWS.
I am not sure how it's impacting the Liquibase.

**A temporary solution is to uninstall the patch and install another java version.**

yum remove log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch.noarch
yum install java-11-openjdk-11.0.12.0.7-0.amzn2.0.2.x86_64